# Postgresql easiest way to replace ID's with Names

Tags: postgresql

**In Postgresql:**

Say I have a table `Dogs`:

```
SELECT * FROM "Dogs"
...
Name        OwnerID
'Pooch'     'OWR14'
'Sparky'    'OWR12'
'Pooch'     'OWR17'
```

And a table `Owners`:

```
SELECT * FROM "Owners"
...
ID         Name
'OWR14'    'Peter'
'OWR12'    'Jack'
'OWR17'    'Mary'
```

**What is the fastest/easiest way to replace the `OwnerID` field with the `Name` values from the `Owner` table?**

My fastest way:

```
SELECT "Dogs"."Name", "Owners"."Name" AS "Owner"
FROM "Dogs"
LEFT JOIN "Owners" ON "Dogs"."OwnerID" = "Owners"."ID"
...
Name        Owner
'Pooch'     'Peter'
'Sparky'    'Jack'
'Pooch'     'Mary'
```

Comment: The fastest easier way would be to use owner name in the 'dogs' table, but what you've done there looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

looking to your sample could be  an upodate with  join

```
UPDATE Dogs
SET Dogs.OwnerID = Owners.Name
FROM Owners
WHERE Dogs.OwnerID = Owners.id;
```

Otherwise if you just need  a faster query  then be sure you have proper composite index  on  table Dogs

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx1 on "Dogs" ("OwnerID", "Name" )
```

and for table Owners

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx2 on "Owners" ("ID", "Name" )
```

Comment: No I don't want to change the data, I am only looking for the fastest query solution